# How do I make FlexBuilder recognize my MXML files as applications instead of components?

Tags: apache-flex, flexbuilder

I am attempting to import mxml files that I developed with Emacs into a new project in FlexBuilder...I have created a project and manually added all my MXML and actionscript files into FlexBuilder.

I now can't figure out how to run the application. I believe the problem lies in the fact that FlexBuilder believes that all my mxml files are components, when in fact, they are applications...Is there a way to change this?

When I right click on the file the "set as default application" and "run application" is disabled...

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I usually seem to have to go into the Project Properties, click 'Flex Applications' and add the MXMLs into that panel before I can run stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the MXML files are in the main source folder.  You can't have a runnable application in a secondary source directory or subdirectory of the main source dir.

Answer (score 0):

Also you have to make sure the root node of the mxml file is Application or Module.

Answer (score 0):

You'll be having 1 file that includes < mx:Application > tag, so FlexBuilder may give you right click -> Run application option for it.

Or what else you can do is, Go to "flex project->properties->Flex Applications"
You can mention ur application here with "add" button

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to the ActionScript project
you can have runnable application at an inner package.
Just go into the the .actionScriptProperties
and add application to the application tag:

```
<applications> 
<application path="com/example/games/game1/Main.as"/> 
<application path="com/example/games/game2/Main.as"/> 
</applications>
```

Answer (score 0):

Open your **.actionScriptProperties** file in your favorite text editor

Look for the **applications** section and add **REPLACE_WITH_REAL_NAME.mxml**

```
  <applications>
    <application path="EnvioManualExtractos.mxml"/>
    <application path="REPLACE_WITH_REAL_NAME.mxml"/>
  </applications>
```

Close the project, reopen it and clean it and build it again